# C# Array Creation

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, expandoobject

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create array of dynamic generic ExpandoObject elements.

I started with this statement, which works:

```
/* WORKS */
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string,object>;
```

What I want is an array composed of such objects. The syntax I tried is this:

```
/* DOES NOT WORK */    
var expandoArray = new ExpandoObject[] as IDictionary<string, object>
{
    new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>,
    new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>
};
```

The idea is that after expandoArray is created, I could refer to its elements as a dynamic by using a construct like this (see http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Feb/01/Dynamic-Types-and-DynamicObject-References-in-C):

```
dynamic expandoArrayDynamic = expandoArray[x];
```

So, my two specific questions are:
1. How do I create an array of Expando as IDictionary objects?
2. How do I view the array elements as dynamic objects?

Comment: `ExpandoObject` implicitly implementes `IDictionary<string,object>` and thus the cast isn't necessary.

Comment: Surely the cast `ExpandoObject[] as IDictionary<string, object>` is not valid, it should be like: `ExpandoObject[] as IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>`?

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding the `as` keyword.

Comment: @Mike: As stated, the cast works (as shown in comment).

Comment: @SLaks: Not sure what you mean--the first code sample uses IDictionary<string, object> correctly. If it doesn't please explain rather than simply chastise.

Comment: `as` is just a cast.  `Dynamic` ignores compile-time types, so `as` doesn't do anything.

Comment: So maybe I misunderstood "dynamic", not "as"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
var expandoArray = new IDictionary<string, object>[]
{
    new ExpandoObject(),
    new ExpandoObject(),
};
```